# Zend Framework 1.10.7 telephone validator

Tags: php, zend-framework

**Please See Correct Answer for solution to the requested question.**

Hi,
Recently I have been searching for telephone validation in zend framework  which I think is a missing component of their Validator framework. Therefore I created custom telephone validator which I would like to share with you.

---

**Put code below in a file accessible by require_once php statement. Here we suppose that this code is pasted in file telephoneValidator.php.**

```
class Custom_Validator_Telephone extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
 const INVALID = 'This field is required';
 protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::INVALID => "Incorrect telephone number"
 );
 public function __construct()
 {
 }
 public function isValid($value) 
 {
  if(preg_match("/^(\+)?(\([0-9]+\)\-?\s?)*([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)*([0-9]+)*$/", trim($value))) 
  {
   return true;
  }  
  else
  {
   $this->_error(self::INVALID);
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

**How to Use it: Put $tel Zend_Element below in your Zend_Form object with addElement method**

```
require_once("telephoneValidator.php")
$tel = new Zend_Form_Element_Text($fieldName);
$telValidator = new Custom_Validator_Telephone();

$tel->addValidator($telValidator, true)
    ->setAllowEmpty(false)
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => array(
                    'isEmpty' => $label.' is required')))   
 ->setLabel("Telephone Number");

$form->addElement($tel);
```

**Error message from this validator can be modified using *setMessage* method of Zend_Validate_Abstract class**

```
$telValidator->setMessage("%value% is not correct telephone number");
$tel->addValidator($telValidator, true)
```

This validator is working fine with phone numbers in following format

```
   +(92) 345-5141637
   +(92)-345-5141637 
   (92) 345-5141637
   (92)-345-5141637
   +(92)-345-5141637 
   92-345-5141637
   +92-345-5141637
   +923455141637 
   923455141637 
   (92)-(345)-5141637
```

I have'nt put length check yet on phone number but it will require to **create a filter for filtering digits** from the input telephone phone number then using **StringLength** 
validator. 
Although I am new in Zend framework, I would like to know that how can I automatically include my classes in **custom folders** inside **application folder** using autoloader of Zend framework. For example I have my custom classes in **MajorClasses folder** inside application folder, please tell me the way to automatically include all the classes inside my MajorClasses folder just be specifying its name because there can be many files inside that folder but I want them to be included automatically. ***Is this possible in Zend framework?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question comes under Zend Resource auotloading http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html

In short, in order to include all files under particular folder we need to follow following rules.

1) Suppose all files under MajorClasses folder are started by Custom i.e. class **Custom_validator_Telephone**, so our namespace for this folder is **Custom**. In order to include files under this folder we need to create an instance of zend resource autoloader

```
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
          'basePath'  => "/path/to/MajorClasses",
          'namespace' => 'Custom'
      ));
```

2) Now we have our resource autoloader ready, we need to add resources to this object for example if I have folder with name validators inside MajorClasses folder and all files inside of this folder are prefixed by **Custom_Validator** then namespace of this folder is **Validator** because we have already defined Custom as prefix of the parent resource object.

```
$resourceLoader->addResourceType('validator', 'validators/', 'Validator');
```

Here

- 1st parameter says about name of resource we are adding and is used for internal recognition.
- 2nd parameter defines path of the folder relative to the base Path we declared when instantiating resource autoloader object, so path of this resource is /path/to/MajorClasses/validators/.
- 3rd parameter specifies namespace of the class i.e. it will be concatenated by the resource object's namespace(in our case it is **Custom**) so prefix of complete class upto this point is **Custom_Validator** and php file inside this folder will be postfixed with this class name after stripping .php file extension

3) Now we can put Telephone.php inside validators folder and if we place above code in bootstrap's any function for e.g. _initPlaceHolders then we can create instance of **Custom_Validator_Telephone** anywhere in our application without need of using require_once statement.

```
$telValidator = new Custom_Validator_Telephone();
```

Comment: This way does NOT work for me, you see your version is NOT 1.10.7, since you asked specifically about 1.10.7 I gave you the correct answer for that version, if it didn't work for that version well you didn't have that version. Don't just assume yours is the "correct" way of doing just because it works for you. The reason it gives you errors and class not found is because you're using an older version.

Comment: i am using 1.10.7 see its documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html for resource autoloader and also http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.html . It is pretty much clear how to use it. Are you referring to Resource autoloading or some other topic, does your method requires some extra settings in application.ini or bootstrap.

Comment: Did you read about the autoloader? Or just Loader? Right next to your link http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Answer (score 1):

Why did you post your full telphone stuff? Your question is just how do you enable autoload of custom files in Zend? Right?

In Zend 1.10.7 you can add the following to public/index.php ABOVE your bootstrap->run command

```
require_once "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('Custom');
```

You can register as many custom namespaces as you like. In this case Custom is a new namespace thus your classes should be named as follows.

```
class Custom_Validator_Telephone extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
```

Now about your directory structure, first question your MajorClasses folder is inside application/??? if so ok, in the same file, as above, there should be a set_include_path() function being run. Within it your setting your library path, now we can add the path to your new directory.

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
    APPLICATION_PATH.'/MajorClasses'.PATH_SEPARATOR,
)));
```

WITHIN MajorClasses folder you will NOW have to create a directory FOR EACH namespace. So if you have the namespace Custom, you create the directory, also you have to create the Validator directory since you're naming it like that, so your path would be.

```
application/MajorClasses/Custom/Validator/Telephone.php
```

Telephone.php should be the name of your class file, the class filename is always the last namespace in the classname.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this info. After performing above steps I can remove require_once statements for file containing  Custom_Validator_Telephone in order to use this validator? Also in order to create object of this validator will I use $telValidator = new Custom_Validator_Telephone(); or $telValidator = new Telephone(); ?

Comment: Please view correct answer. Yours are giving lots of errors about class not found or declared.

Comment: Viper_Sb's answer is the correct one, if you are creating library-style functionality use the normal autoloader. Resource autoloaders are only really for things within your application or module such as Models, Forms, etc. There is a typo, however. The line where you register the autloader should be: $autoloader->registerNamespace('Custom_');